# How to update the value of object properties inside array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
 const seconDarydata = [
    { value: 1, label: "desc1" },
    { value: 2, label: "desc2" },
    { value: 3, label: "desc3" },
    { value: 4, label: "desc4" },
    { value: 5, label: "desc5" },
    { value: 6, label: "desc6" }
  ];
  const primarydata = [{ value: 1, label: "primaryAdd1" }];

  const [primaryAdd, setPrimayAdd] = useState(primarydata);
  const [secondaryAdd, setSecondaryAdd] = useState(seconDarydata);


const onClickHandler = index => {
    let oldPrimatLocations = primaryAdd;
    let newPrimaryLocation = secondaryAdd[index];
    
    let objIndex = secondaryAdd.findIndex(
      obj => obj.value === oldPrimatLocations[0].value
    );

    secondaryAdd[objIndex + 1].label = oldPrimatLocations[0].label;
    setPrimayAdd([newPrimaryLocation]);
    setSecondaryAdd(secondaryAdd);
  };
  

<div>
      <h5>Primay Data</h5>
      <h6>{primaryAdd[0].label}</h6>
      <h6>Secondary Data</h6>
      {secondaryAdd.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {index}
            <button id={item.value} onClick={() => onClickHandler(index)}>
              {item.label}
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

I have two array and use initial state with this array inside useState.
My goal is to implement the swap functionality.

so here if user is  click on secondaryData , it will swap with the primary data.
I tried all the things but missing something.
could some one let me know what are missing condition onClickHandler.
is there possible using ... operator.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55692229/11486991). Notice the use of the `...` operator as you mentioned, which creates a new array/object instead of "mutating" (directly modifying) the current state. Mutating state is something you can't do in React, you have to create a new state object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you are mutating state objects:

```
const onClickHandler = index => {
  let oldPrimatLocations = primaryAdd;
  let newPrimaryLocation = secondaryAdd[index];

  let objIndex = secondaryAdd.findIndex(
    obj => obj.value === oldPrimatLocations[0].value
  );

  secondaryAdd[objIndex + 1].label = oldPrimatLocations[0].label; // mutate state and mix up index
  setPrimayAdd([newPrimaryLocation]);
  setSecondaryAdd(secondaryAdd); // saved mutate state reference back in state
};
```

**Solve:** If I understand correctly, if "primaryAdd1" is in primary array and a user clicks on "desc3" then the two values swap places. Now "desc3" is in primary array and "primaryAdd1" is in secondary array at index 2.

```
primary: ["desc3"]
secondary: ["desc1", "desc2", "primaryAdd1", "desc4", "desc5", "desc6"]
```

If user now clicks "desc6", it swaps and is now in primary array and "desc3" is in secondary array at index 5.

```
primary: ["desc6"]
secondary: ["desc1", "desc2", "primaryAdd1", "desc4", "desc5", "desc3"]
```

**Solution:** extract the old and new primary location objects, place the newPrimaryLocation in primary array and place the oldPrimaryLocation in the secondary array *at* the same index

```
const onClickHandler = index => {
  const oldPrimaryLocation = primaryAdd[0];
  const newPrimaryLocation = secondaryAdd[index];

  setPrimaryAdd([newPrimaryLocation]);
  setSecondaryAdd(secondaryAdd =>
    // functional update and map to return new array reference
    secondaryAdd.map((el, i) => (i === index ? oldPrimaryLocation : el))
  );
};
```

[image: Edit delicate-pond-p72wl]

Different implementation to copy the arrays first, do the swap, and just save the copied arrays in state.

```
const onClickHandler = index => {
  const primary = [...primaryAdd];
  const secondary = [...secondaryAdd];

  [secondary[index], primary[0]] = [primary[0], secondary[index]];

  setPrimaryAdd(primary);
  setSecondaryAdd(secondary);
};
```

Comment: [secondary[index], primary[0]] = [primary[0], secondary[index]]; what is the meaning of this ? it will copy primary[0] to secondary[index] and vice versa.

Comment: @Patel Array [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Yes, it will swap them, i.e. `a=37; b=13; [b, a] = [a, b]; console.log('a', a, 'b', b); // a 13 b37` Copy/paste this to your browser console to test. BTW, the `useState` hook also uses destructuring assignment. ;)